# iPad Startup Screen Shrinks

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm trying to get an iphone/ipad app startup screen set up.  Currently on the ipad it shows the correct large version then switches to the smaller iphone image.  Any ideas on why this would happen?

In my plist file I have the UILaunchImageFile~ipad set up as iPad and the image files are iPad-Landscape.png and iPad-Portrait.png.  They are 1004x768 and 768x1004 respectively.  The iphone image is just Default.png.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a daft suggestion, but is your code displaying the iphone version in the first view it puts on screen?

Often people do this to make their app display the splashscreen for longer than the Apple default.

Comment: Not a daft suggestion at all, I've done a lot sillier things than that before!  It looks like this isn't the issue though this time.